# Voronoi polygons for a layer with point objects, attributes are lost for points with different attributes but same coordinates

Tags: qgis, voronoi-thiessen

I use QGIS v3.4.

I have a layer with points where some points has exactly the same coordinates but different attribute fields. When I generate voronoi polygons for this layer the attributes of the points with the same coordinates are lost. The point objects are address objects, some buildings have multiple house numbers but the same coordinate. Most address objects have different coordinates, the generation of voronoi polygons works good except for these points with the same coordinates.

I need the attributes for the dissolve process where I can compute min and max for the hous numbers (from/to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to solve my issue by not using the min/max values from the GDAL Dissolve process but by using *"Join attributes by location (summary)"* after *Dissolve*. `Count` (#adresses), `min` (`housenr_low`) and `max` (`housenr_high`) can be selected. The Joined layer is the Dissolve layer and the point layer is the Join layer.